# Use name of selector as value for a variable in SASS

Tags: variables, sass, css-selectors

I'd like to take the ID of a div that I'm applying styling to and set a variable to have that ID as its value. Is this something Sass can do? So the selector `#eleven` would set the value of a variable to "eleven".

Here's the current code. First a mixin that I'm using:

```
@mixin left-icon ($bgcolor, $bgurl, $iconmargin) {
    background: $bgcolor url(images/#{$bgurl}.png) no-repeat left 5px center;
    & h2, & p {margin-left: $iconmargin;}
}
```

And this is when I call the mixin:

```
#eleven {
    @include left-icon(#de4c3f,eleven,$defaulticonmargin);
}
```

So when I used that mixin there's a background color, part of a file name, and a value for margins (which are added to some child selectors) that are set. As you can see the `$bgurl` variable matches the selector's name. Basically I want to automate that so that the `$bgurl` will be set to the text string from the ID (with the hash symbol stripped).

The reason being that I'm going to have dozens of boxes with the same basic pattern but unique background image and it seems, in my head, the simplest thing to do would be to save each PNG using the ID name as the file name and then let Sass match them up. I could just do as I have done here and put the value in longhand but it seems like something Sass might do so I'd rather spend time getting it right and learning more about Sass than do half a job.

Hope that makes sense and isn't a ridiculously stupid question – I will admit (and you won't be surprised to hear) that I'm a very raw Sass recruit but I figure I can learn from this question.

Comment: Yes, only just came back to this. Pezholio's solution does exactly what I need. I will have a look at implementing yours too but its not wholly clear to me how it answers the problem – that's a limitation with my knowledge and hopefully I'll learn more about SASS by trying your version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@mixin left-icon ($bgcolor, $bgurl, $iconmargin) {
  ##{$bgurl} {
    background: $bgcolor url(images/#{$bgurl}.png) no-repeat left 5px center;
& h2, & p {margin-left: $iconmargin;}
  }
}

@include left-icon(#de4c3f,eleven,10px);
```

Basically, you can add variables anywhere using Sass's [interpolation syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

Comment: That is very cool, thanks for replying.

For anyone else new to SASS trying to follow this through to the end it's worth clarifying that this requires a bit of a change of logic over the way I outlined the problem: in my scenario I was trying to pass the selector name to the variable in the @include, in the solution we in fact name the selector when we call the mixing with the include – it achieves the effect but the logic in my question was back to front :O)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead to make it simpler is use IDs or classes called `b11` (or `bg11`, the letters are arbitrary)

```
$colorArray = [ #de4c3f, ... ];
@for $i from $min through $max {
    .b#{$i} {
        @include left-icon(colorArray[$i], $i, $defaulticonmargin);
    }
}
```

and then change the background names to match the new format, as in `images/#11.png` *or* you can use [this process](http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/01/15/sass-string-to-number/) to convert the string to an int

This way you can define all of your elements recursively!